# Is there a way to make markers/icons/text appear in the website depending on the position of a slider?

Tags: html, date, slider

I attempting to make a website which would have a slider that which the websites user could slide to set a specific date. Under the slider I am planning to have a map on which markers would appear/move/disappear depending on where the slider is located. So far, with the help of this great community here (RobG specifically), I have a working slider, a map and pretty much everything else except I can't find a way how to make these markers or icons or text appear in the website depending on the position of the slider.

For an example of the slider look here: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_rangeslider

How can I make things appear or dissapear on the website depending on the slider?

Edit for Aditya Prakash. Here is the full code with the scripts I tried to add:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.slidecontainer {
      width: 100%;
    }

    .slider {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      width: 100%;
      height: 25px;
      background: #d3d3d3;
      outline: none;
      opacity: 0.7;
      -webkit-transition: .2s;
      transition: opacity .2s;
    }

    .slider:hover {
      opacity: 1;
    }

    .slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
      -webkit-appearance: none;
      appearance: none;
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background: #4CAF50;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .slider::-moz-range-thumb {
      width: 25px;
      height: 25px;
      background: #4CAF50;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <h1>Custom Range Slider</h1>

    <div class="slidecontainer">
      <p>Default range slider:</p>
      <input type="range" min="1" max="100" value="50">

      <p>Custom range slider:</p>
      <input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" class="slider" id="myRange" step="0.1">
    </div>

 <script>
        myRange.onchange=function() {
        var fader = document.getElementById('myRange');
        document.getElementById('https://www.mapsofindia.com/worldmap/map-of-world.jpg').style.opacity = fader.value;
        }

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following script to make it work

```
  <script>
        myRange.onchange=function() {
        var fader = document.getElementById('myRange');
        document.getElementById('pic').style.opacity = fader.value;
        }

    </script>
```

The 'pic' ID will be the ID of the image.

Edit:
You will also need to change the value of your slider to range from 0 to 1. Use the following line.

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="1" value="0.5" class="slider" id="myRange" step="0.1">
```

Comment: Thank you! But for some reason it doesn't work for me, I added the script at the bottom of my html page and edited the value of the slider as you specified in the edit. Then I set some test image in the 'pic' section but there appears to be no change, what am I doing wrong? I will post the full code with what I did in the main post in the edit.

Comment: "document.getElementById('https://www.mapsofindia.com/worldmap/map-of-world.jpg').style.opacity = fader.value;" Is wrong. You have to add the image with <img> tag, and give it an ID. eg. pic. Your correct syntax would be: <img src="https://www.mapsofindia.com/worldmap/map-of-world.jpg" id="pic">

Comment: Also, it is a bad practice to add style and script tags in the same file. You should be using different files for them and use a link tag to link them.